# Generate and echo thumbnail from video

Tags: php, html, css

I have an mp4 video at `dir/video.mp4`, is there any possible way to generate a thumbnail based on whatever may be at 0:10 into the video and then output it as possibly an img tag? I'm using PHP

Comment: not directly in PHP, there might be something in your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done with php. You need a apache module called as "FFMPEG", If you are having dedicated server you can install it. Otherwise you can ask your server administrator to get it installed.

Please have look at [this video](https://youtu.be/IxpAOmvawyw?t=7), it can help you in image cropping. It need some tweaks but yeah you can do it by watching this tutorial.